# Using Grunt to Replace Text in a File

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

I'm trying to get Grunt to replace a path reference and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.  This looks like it should work.  Essentially, I'm copying a Bootstrap file up a directory and changing the @import paths, so I'm just trying to replace 'bootstrap/' with the new destination path 'MY/NEW/DEST/PATH/bootstrap'.  I don't want to use a module for something as straight forward as this, seems needless.  Everything works but the replace.

```
var destFilePath = path.join(basePath, file);

// Does the file already exist?
if (!grunt.file.exists(destFilePath)) {

    // Copy Bootstrap source @import file to destination
    grunt.file.copy(

        // Node API join to keep this cross-platform
        path.join(basePath, 'bootstrap/_bootstrap.scss'),
        destFilePath
    );

    // Require node filesystem module, since not a global
    var fs = require('fs');

    // Replace @import paths to be relative to new destination                                
    fs.readFile(destFilePath, 'utf8', function(err, data) {

        // Check for any errs during read
        if (err) {
            return grunt.log.write(err);
        }

        var result = data.replace('/bootstrap\//g', 'bootstrap/bootstrap/');

        fs.writeFile(destFilePath, result, 'utf8', function(err) {
            return grunt.log.write(err);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: what is it actually doing vs. what you expect it to do?

Comment: it's not replacing 'bootstrap/' of the @import path to 'my/path/', doesn't replace anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrapped your regex in quotes - don't do that and it should work fine:

```
var result = data.replace(/bootstrap\//g, 'bootstrap/bootstrap/');
```

Comment: btw... you can use grunt.file.read and grunt.file.write instead of using `fs`... and your grunt.file.copy is not necessary since you promptly overwrite the file

Comment: Hmmm, it still doesn't seem to work, the @import line is still: "bootstrap/variables"; and not "bootstrap/bootstrap/variables"; but using your suggestion above and not using fs worked first try with the same code.  Thanks for the help